# How to disable Console.WriteLine() in release mode?

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can disable `Console.WriteLine()` in release mode?

I want to use `Console.WriteLine()` only in debug mode but not in release mode.

Comment: Can you not replace `Console.WriteLine` calls with `Debug.WriteLine` or `Trace.WriteLine` calls?

Comment: Use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`.

Comment: You can also have breakpoints print to the screen.

Comment: Why all those down votes yet no solutions are supplied in equal measure?

Comment: @Joebacio can't speak to why people downvoted, but It doesn't seem like you 
didn't answer any of the other comments. vc 74's comment about the other outputs (debug and trace) is in itself a answer.  Debug will do what you ask, write out when running a debug build, and not from a release build.  You also have a answer, albeit that answer could use more explanation, but it can lead you in a good direction if debug.writeline and trace.writeline don't work.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `Console.Writeline`

Instead use `Debug.Writeline` or `Trace.WriteLine`.

This is what they were made for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the #if preprocessor. This is a good example:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

You can find more information on [Microsoft Docs #if (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).

Comment: My suggestion is that you were downvoted because `#if DEBUG` is not a quite solid solution. Imagine you have tons of Console.WriteLine() through your code and each of them has 2 extra lines with ifdef and endif. Much better option it to handle that under logic under the good, e.g. `Debug.WriteLine()`

Comment: While not preferable, this answer is still useful. Have an offsetting upvote.

Answer (score -1):

The answer from @DaniloDebiaziVicente would work, but if you wish to avoid the `#IF` pre-processor you could use the following. Basically you create a debug variable and toggle it back and forth depending on which version you are targeting. This requires a little more manual work but may be more intuitive to implement.

```
bool debug = true; // or `false`

if (debug) {
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
}
```